# Gmail doesn't include Hotmail recipients in reply-all

Tags: gmail

I just noticed that, on a thread that includes about 4 Gmail addresses, one Hotmail, and one Google Group, reply-all doesn't include the Hotmail address. Is this a known issue?

Comment: That sounds crazy! I just tried this with a thread of 20+ addresses, including at least 2 Hotmail and both were included in the reply when doing a reply-all.

Comment: sounds crazy, but it's still happening...

Comment: Nope, sounds ridiculous, actually. Edit: Just confirmed. I have participated in a conversation using many reply alls to many different providers, including Hotmail, as recently as yesterday, and it worked perfectly.

Comment: Just to clarify, is the Hotmail address omitted _before_ the email is sent ie. when composing? Or once it has been sent, the Hotmail recipients just don't receive it and those addresses are not present in the _sent_ email? Are these Hotmail addresses in the "To:" field?

Comment: Sounds like a bug. Is it still happening?